Solve the system of differential equations associated with an ellipsoid.
Consider the ellipsoid, given by
$$
f(u, v) = \bigl( a\sin(u)\cos(v), b\sin(u)\sin(v), c\cos(u) \bigr), 
\quad 0 \leq u \leq \pi, 
\quad 0 \leq v \leq 2\pi, 
$$
and consider the $1$-form in $\Bbb R^2$ given by $w = dx-z\,dy$.
By considering the directional field arising from the intersection of the kernel of the differential form at each point, we can obtain the following system of equations
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= abc \cos^2(t)\sin(t) \\ 
\frac{dy}{dt} &= ab \cos(t)\sin(t) \\
\frac{dz}{dt} &= c \sin^2(t)\bigl(-bc \cos(t)\cos(v) - a\sin(v)\bigr)
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
How can I solve this system of equations, as it seems to be not very intuitive, any suggestions?
A graphical approximation of the directional field is more or less the following


By solving, in what form do you want your results to be?

Why don't you just pull back the $1$-form $\omega$ by the parametrization $f$? The ODE will be $f^*\omega=0$. In $(u,v)$-space you will have $A(u,v)du+B(u,v)dv=0$, and this is solved (perhaps not easily) just like all the ODE we study in introductory differential equations courses.

@TedShifrin  Could you please clarify the ODE deduction?

We have $\omega = dx-z\,dy$. Then
\begin{align*}
f^*\omega &= d(a\sin u\cos v) - (c\cos u)d(b\sin u\sin v) \\
&= a(\cos u\cos v\,du - \sin u\sin v\,dv) - bc(\cos^2u\sin v\,du + \cos u\sin u\cos v\,dv) \\
&= \big(a\cos u\cos v-bc\cos^2u\sin v\big)du - \big(a\sin u\sin v + bc\cos u\sin u\cos v\big)dv.
\end{align*}
So you want to solve the ODE $$\big(a\cos u\cos v-bc\cos^2u\sin v\big)du - \big(a\sin u\sin v + bc\cos u\sin u\cos v\big)dv=0.$$
Of course, this is not exact, since $d\omega\ne 0$. But theory tells us that since $f^*\omega$ is never the $0$-form, the integral curves of this ODE give us a foliation of the ellipsoid. You may be clever enough to find an integrating factor, or you can integrate numerically.

Thanks for your valuable input, I just have a small doubt, I guess my idea of intersecting the planes in the ellipsoid and generating the straight lines is summarized to your idea that the pullback takes the value of zero, or exactly what is the consequence of the pullback being zero?

Pulling back is more natural, as we then are working "on" the surface directly, rather than in $\Bbb R^3$. Of course, the kernel of the differential form is precisely what I'm doing when I write down $f^*\omega=0$.
